# Definition of type variable and parameter

Tags: java, generics, definition

I am reading up on generics in Java using the *Java Language Specification, Third edition*. In section "[4.6 Erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.6)" type erasure is defined. On the erasure of a type variable it says

> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

This confuses me a bit regarding the distinction between *type variable* and *type parameter* since section "[4.4 Type Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850)" has the definition: `TypeParameter: TypeVariable TypeBound` where the bound is optional. But perhaps you can identify a type variable with the type parameter it appears in since a type variable can only (?) appear in one "context" and then a type variable's leftmost bound is defined as the leftmost bound of its corresponding type parameter or `Object` in case there is no explicit bound appearing in the type parameter ?

Answer (score 6):

> If no bound is given for a type variable, Object is assumed.

Found in your link. That means that given `FirstClass<T extends String>` and `SecondClass<V>` you get that:

1. Class: `FirstClass` Type Parameter: `T extends String`. Type Variable: `T`. Type Bound: `String`.
2. Class: `SecondClass` Type Parameter: `V` Type Variable: `V`. Type Bound: defaults to `Object`.

**Edit:** By **Type Parameter**, **Type Variable** and **Type Bound** I do not mean the grammar rule, but the concept. Therefore, `extends` is just the keyword.

About the leftmost bound you can find the answer in the same link, two sentences after the first quote:

> The order of types in a bound is only significant in that the erasure of a type variable is determined by the first type in its bound, and that a class type or type variable may only appear in the first position.

Comment: Your example doesn't explain if in the definition of erasure of a type variable, "leftmost bound" formally corresponds to the leftmost bound in the type parameter the type variable appears in. Wouldn't the erasure of your examples be the erasure of `FirstClass` and the erasure of `SecondClass` and assuming these are just class names, the erasure would equal the names ? Type variables exist independently of type bounds in the grammar but type bounds appear as optional parts of type parameters. Strictly speaking, `extends` is part of the type bound.

Comment: Yes, if I had written __TypeBound__ the grammar rule. Two sentences after the previous quote you can read that: "The order of types in a bound is only significant in that the erasure of a type variable is determined by the first type in its bound, and that a class type or type variable may only appear in the first position." I'll edit the answer to includ it.

Answer (score 4):

***TL;DR*** — **Context is everything!**

---

Informally, "*type variable*" and "*type parameter*" are used interchangeably as synonyms for each other [[*even by Gilad Bracha — the creator of Java's Generics implementation*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)].

Formally, however, [*the JLS*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) explicitly describes them as two different — *but closely-related* — abstractions.

In the past, I have had similar questions myself about the less-than-crystal-clear usage of the terms "*type parameter*" and "*type variable*" in a lot of the literature on generics.

From my interpretation of [*the more-recent Java 8 JLS*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2), a *`TypeParameter`* is what appears in a parameterized class' or method's type parameter section [*the `<>` part of a declaration*].

[*The JLS says, "**A type variable is introduced by the declaration of a type parameter***..."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4). I interpret that to mean that, in order to use a *`TypeVariable`*, you must first fill out the method's [*or the class'*] type parameter section by following the rules specified for declaring a *`TypeParameter`*...

```
TypeParameter:
    {TypeParameterModifier} Identifier [TypeBound]

TypeParameterModifier:
    Annotation

TypeBound:
    extends TypeVariable
    extends ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}

AdditionalBound:
    & InterfaceType
```

Reading [*the above syntactic production for `TypeParameter`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeParameter) and [*this one for `TypeVariable`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeVariable)...

```
TypeVariable:
    {Annotation} Identifier
```

...I interpret those two productions to mean that if an identifier *`T`* is being used in a context where *`T`* has [*or can have*] a  *`TypeBound`* after it, then *`T`* is a *`TypeParameter`*. Alternatively, if an identifier *`T`* is being used in a context where *`TypeBound`s* are not allowed, then *`T`* is a *`TypeVariable`*.

---

I think of a *`TypeParameter`* as being analogous to a ***formal parameter*** of a method declaration.

When [*the JLS says, "**A type variable is an unqualified identifier used as a type in class, interface, method, and constructor bodies***"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4), I interpret that to mean that declaring a *`TypeParameter`* in the type parameter section, is also sort of analogous to declaring a class  that can be subsequently used as a reference type of, say, an instance variable — *in a sense*.

By that I mean, in order for the following to be legal...

```
class Foo { 

   private Bar bar;
}

class Boff extends Foo { }
```

..then you must first ***introduce** the declaration of the `Bar` type* before it can be used in the body of *`Foo`*. Analogously, the type parameter *`<T extends Foo>`* must first be declared in order for the following to be legal...

```
class Baz<T extends Foo> { /* The TypeParameter that "introduces" T comes first */

    private T quux; /* now T is  a TypeVariable in this context */

    /* <U extends Number> is the TypeParameter that "introduces" the TypeVariable, U */

    public <U extends Number> List<? super U> m( Class<U> clazz ) throws Exception { /* <U extends Number> is the TypeParameter */

        U u = clazz.newInstance( ); /* U is a TypeVariable in this context */

        /*...*/

        List<? super U> list = new LinkedList<>(); /* U is a TypeVariable in this context; just like it is in this method's return type */          

        /*...*/

        list.add( u );

        /*...*/

        return list;

    }

}
```

---

And if I'm allowed to be even more specific...

```
Baz<Boff> buzz = new Baz<>();
```

...the *`Boff`* inside the *`<>`* diamond, is neither a *type **variable*** nor a *type **parameter***. It is a *type **argument*** .