# What is meant by left most bound for generic type or a method and why was this policy chosen for type erasure?

Tags: java, generics

From [Angelika Langer's generic FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ100):

**Eliding type parameters.**

> When the compiler finds the definition of a generic type or method, it
>   removes all occurrences of the type parameters and replaces them by
>   their leftmost bound, or type Object if no bound had been specified.

Edit: As I understood in this case *leftmost bound* means what it means literally i.e farthest to the left in the list of bounds. I want to understand why was this policy chosen?

Comment: The most permissive; i.e. a type which all parameters can be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075363/definition-of-type-variable-and-parameter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case "leftmost" is not technical terminology. It literally means "farthest to the left". It simply means that when the type parameter has several bounds (restrictions) like this:

```
T extends Callable<Long> & Runnable
```

the compiler replaces all occurances of the type parameter `T` with the bound that is farthest to the left (in this case that's `Callable<Long>`):

Meaning that, as in Angelika's example, this:

```
private T task1, task2;
```

is replaced with this:

```
private Callable task1, task2;
```

Comment: why did they choose "the farthest from the left policy"?

Comment: It's not "farthest from the left", it's "farthest to the left", and I wouldn't know why they did it, but I assume one reason is that when there's a class bound involved, that has to be listed first, so the leftmost rule would automatically choose that one.

Comment: Another reason for choosing the leftmost bound is to make the choice well defined so that the user has control over the type used in the erased class.  You want this so that you can craft classes to be backwards compatible for old code. i.e. If you want the "raw" erased class to extend a particular type or an erased generic method to have a particular argument type you can control that by choosing the bound.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason. They just need to pick one. The whole thing sucks. It's like asking which one of your children you want to save. You want to save all, duh. But they don't let you.